# How to deal with Money in Rails and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I know this question has been asked before, but most answers I've found are related to ActiveRecord or old (most cases, both) and I was wondering whether there's a new take on this.

Is short, my Rails app is an API, so please keep this in mind (can't normally use lots of helpful little view related helpers).

I've been reading about this and found the [MoneyRails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) which seems quite neat. The problem I'm having with it is that when I retrieve the data, it returns an object instead of the an usable value:

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  field :price_GBP,  type: Money
  ...
end
```

So to create the document I send a number and it created the document fine. Now when I query the same document it returns an object for `price_GBP`, which is fine, but my main grip is that it return the value `fractional` as in `my_obj.price_GBP[:fractional]` as a string rather than a number.

I'd rather not have my client to have to do the conversion fro string to number than to decimal.

I guess I could create a little helper that would convert the value in such circumstances like so (in my Model):

```
def my_helper
  self.price_GBP = BigDecimal(self.price_GBP) # or something along those lines
end
```

Then in my controller:

```
@my_model = Model.find(id)
@my_model.price_GBP = @my_model.price_GBP = @my_model.my_helper
render json: @my_model
```

With the above in mind, would this be the best approach? If yes, what's the point of using the MoneyRails gem then?

Secondly, if not using the MoneyRails gem, should I use `BigDecimal` or `Float` as the field type?

When I tried `BigDecimal`, the data was saved ok, but when I've retrieve it, I got an string rather than a number. Is this the correct behaviour?

When I tried `Float` it all worked fine, but I read somewhere that `Float` is not the most accurate.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Can you add an irb/pry session showing what you described in this paragraph: "So to create the document I send a number and it created the document fine. Now when I query the same document it returns an object for price_GBP, which is fine, but my main grip is that it return the value fractional as in my_obj.price_GBP[:fractional] as a string rather than a number." ?  If possible, make clear what was the actual result and what instead you expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using `Float` if you're planning on performing any type of arithmetic on the currency values. `BigDecimal` is good or you can also represent the value in cents and store it as an `Integer`. This is actually how the Money gem works.

My recommendation would be to continue to use the MoneyRails gem and use the [built-in helpers](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#helpers) to output the values. You mentioned not being able to use the helpers but I don't see what's preventing that - Rails includes [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) which allows you to formulate your JSON structure in a view with access to all "helpful little view related helpers" - for example

```
# app/views/someresource/show.json.jbuilder

# ...other attributes
json.price_GBP = humanized_money(@my_model.price_GBP)
```

Comment: I don't have any View (API only app) so the helpers don't work. I've tried including `include ActionView::Base` in my model which didn't work. If I use `ActionController::Base.helpers.humanized_money` instead works, though not very elegant. Lastly, when I use jBuilder, all values (including numbers) are being sent as `String` which definitely I do not want. Is this the standard behaviour of jBuilder?

Comment: The `show.json.jbuilder` _IS_ the view - so yes you do have access to the view helpers. As far as I know, jbuilder doesn't convert numbers to strings by default so there might be something else happening in your case.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/bjedrocha/products-example) is a sample application I created that describes the above - please take a look. If you want the money value to come back as a number (so you can perform computation on the client) then use `price.cents` to send back an `integer` instead of the helper. Hope this helps. Thanks.